# Which are the exact differences between Catholics and Protestants?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, global-christianity

I'm a bit confused about the differences, specially in what is canon for each of them.

I think the whole bible is canon for all of them though, I've also hear that new testament can maybe be considered as a whole canon for Protestants.

I'd also like to confirm other differences I've read:

Protestants believe in Christ while Catholics also believe in Virgin Mary and also on saints and adore their figures.

Catholics believe in 7 sacraments while Protestants do not necessarily believe in them.

Catholics believe in Virgin Mary as a saint with no sins meanwhile Protestants do not necessarily believe that.

Catholics do believe in the Pope as leader while Protestants do not necessarily believe in him.

Can you help me to confirm that things or tell me more differences?

Comment: A comment: Catholics regard themselves as Christians; most other Christian denominations do as well.

Answer (score 0):

Quick run down:
When I say 'non Catholics' I generally mean Protestants.

"Christians believe in Christ while Catholics also believe in Virgin Mary and also on saints and adore their figures."
- Catholics also believe in Christ but plenty of Catholics also believe that the way to Christ is via Mary, which non Catholics don't follow because its not in the bible. Catholics also believe that saints can assist them in certain ways in heaven, like each saint has a different purpose. Non Catholics believe no one but God can be prayed to for help and that all believers are saints.

"Catholics believe in 7 sacraments while christians do not necesarily believe in them." - Catholics and non Catholics generally hold similarities with sacraments, such as baptism or confirmation, but non Catholics are less formal towards other practices such as Holy Order.

"Catholics believe in Virgin Mary as a saint with no sins meanwhile chhristians do not necesarily believe that." - According to protestants Mary is a saint, like all believers in Christ, though non Catholics believe all people are born into sin (Romans 2:23) so therefore so was Mary.

"Catholics do believe in the Pope as leader while christians do not necesarily believe in him." - Catholics believe the pope is the leader of the Christian church, as well as Christ, where as non Christians believe Christ is the leader and no other man.

Comment: Welcome! We're glad you are here, but this answer would be much stronger if you showed, with sources, that it doesn't merely reflect your own analysis.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).